# What is wrong is my SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to query my database. 

The is my `SQL` code:

```
SELECT `traveller.ticket_no`,`traveller`.`fname`,`traveller`.`lname`,`destination`.`d_name`,`plane`.`plane_name`,`flights`.`flight_name`
FROM `traveller`,`destination`,`flights`,`plane`,`checked`
WHERE `destination`.`destination_id`=`flights`.`d_id`,`plane`.`plane_id`=`flights`.`p_id`,`checked`.`flight_id`=`flights`.`flight_id`,`checked`.`t_id`=`traveller`.`ticket_no`
AND `traveller`.`ticket_no`="1"
```

The error that I'm getting is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near
>   'plane.plane_id=flights.p_id,checked.flight_id=flights.flight_id,' at
>   line 3

What is wrong in my `SQL` statement. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: With a `WHERE` clause, you need to use `AND` and `OR` types clauses between the different things you want to match.

Comment: Check the dot `destination`.`destination_id`

Comment: Consider using explicit rather than implicit joins.

Comment: I think the problem might be relating the index keys. What syntax is used to relate the index keys and primary keys in an sql statement in phymyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT traveller.ticket_no`,`traveller`.`fname`,`traveller`.`lname`,`destination`.`destination_id`,`destination`.`d_name`,`plane`.`plane_id`,`plane`.`plane_name`,`flights`.`flight_id`,`flights`.`p_id`,`flights`.`d_id`,`flights`.`flight_name`,`checked`.`t_id`,`checked`.`flight_id`

FROM `traveller`,`destination`,`flights`,`plane`,`checked`

WHERE `destination`.`destination_id`=`flights`.`d_id` AND `plane`.`plane_id`=`flights`.`p_id` AND `checked`.`flight_id`=`flights`.`flight_id` AND `checked`.`t_id`=`traveller`.`ticket_no` AND `traveller`.`ticket_no`="1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this helped me

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like

```
SELECT `traveller.ticket_no`,`traveller`.`fname`,`traveller`.`lname`,
        `destination`.`d_name`,`plane`.`plane_name`,
        `flights`.`flight_name`
    FROM `traveller`,`destination`,`flights`,`plane`,`checked`
    WHERE `destination`.`destination_id`=`flights`.`d_id` 
        and `plane`.`plane_id`=`flights`.`p_id` 
        and `checked`.`flight_id`=`flights`.`flight_id` 
        and `checked`.`t_id`=`traveller`.`ticket_no`
        AND `traveller`.`ticket_no`="1"
```

Could also be worth looking into a more up to date [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) syntax.

(Just to add from original comment)  The difference is that you had a comma between the clauses in your `WHERE` statement, so I've changed the commas to `and`.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this query i hope it's working

```
   SELECT `traveller.ticket_no`,`traveller`.`fname`,`traveller`.`lname`,`destination`.`d_name`,`plane`.`plane_name`,`flights`.`flight_name`
    FROM `traveller`,`destination`,`flights`,`plane`,`checked`
    WHERE `destination.destination_id`=`flights.d_id`,`plane.plane_id`=`flights.p_id`,`checked.flight_id`=`flights.flight_id`,`checked.t_id`=`traveller.ticket_no`
    AND `traveller.ticket_no`="1"
```

Comment: is there a different syntax to use?

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
  WHERE `destination`.`destination_id`=`flights`.`d_id` 

    and `plane`.`plane_id`=`flights`.`p_id` 

    and `checked`.`flight_id`=`flights`.`flight_id` 

    and `checked`.`t_id`=`traveller`.`ticket_no`

    AND `traveller`.`ticket_no`="1"
```